# Backend validation of digits by twitter Oauth tokens?

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter-digits

I am making an Android app for signing in/up users. I was using my own API but now I am trying to implement **digits by twitter**.

After a user successfully enters the otp, in my success callback, I want to check that he has been authenticated. Only then will I show him the next activity.

I want to use my backend to authenticate. Which **URL** should I send my Oauth token to validate the token and know what is the mobile number associated with that token?

**Update**- There is also Oauth Echo [Use OAuth Echo](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/oauth-echo.html) but again how this validate the user server side?